# Cannot get Facebook friends array on IE, but working on other browsers

Tags: ajax, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

This function is working on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE9, where errorHandler is logging this error message:

```
ERROR:  getFriendsArray {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"No Transport"}
```

getUserAccessToken() is returning the right value. Any ideas what could it be, that only affects IE?

EDIT: seems that https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends directly on IE browser returns HTTP 400 error.

```
function getFriendsArray() {

    var friendsArray = [];

    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends',
        data: {
            access_token: getUserAccessToken(),
            fields: 'name,picture,gender'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            var data = '';
            $.each(response.data, function(indice, item) {
                friendsArray.push(item);
            });                       
        },
        error: function(err) {
            errorHandler('getFriendsArray', JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });

    return friendsArray.sort(sortByName);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.ajax` only supports using XMLHttpRequest or XDomainRequest (IE), the latter only supporting a few scenarios, and requiring that your page is SSL if the requested resource is SSL.

Instead, use `FB.api`, which handles this and much more, ensuring that the call makes it through, either by using JSONP, XHR, XDomainRequest, or Flash.